# Powershell global variables permissions issue - rewrite help needed

Tags: powershell, variables, scripting

I am trying to write a script that gathers information about files in a folder and outputs to a csv. All works until I modified permissions for the end user (standard user, read+execute, windows) The script fails to capture global variables and though works as script variables, the output is wrong. (script truncated some)

```
$global:filecount = 1
Get-ChildItem C:\temp\data\ -Recurse -include @("*.txt*","*.pdf") |
Select-Object CreationTime,
@{Name = "Date Added";Expression={get-date}},
@{Name = "User Added";E={$env:UserName}},
@{n ='SHA1';e={(Get-FileHash $_ -Algorithm SHA1).Hash}}
@{n ='SHA256';e={(Get-FileHash $_ -Algorithm SHA256).Hash}}
@{n = "Filecount"; Expression = {$global:filecount; $global:filecount++}} |
Export-Csv $output_location -append
```

if global, the output of filecount is 0 under non-administrative accounts. 
if script level variable, and the real filecount is 1, output is    1 1 1

How can I fix this? I'm new to powershell and not a script maker by trade so I may be missing some logic here.

Also, script is about 800 lines long. Every other variable works. Most the script is user inputting variable values that export to csv. Only the filecount fails.

Thank you all.

Edit for clarification
Output creates a csv file such that the fields are formatted below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrIOC.png)

CreationTime    Date Added to DB    User Added to DB by Intel Source    sourceID    FileID  BaseName    Extension   Folder  Kilobytes   SHA1    SHA256  SHA512  MD5

Comment: You should declare `$Global:filecount = 1` instead of `$filecount = 1` since you increment the global `$global:filecount++`  scope later on.

Comment: Thank you. I do declare the variable as $global: and $script: everywhere to match the use in my script above. If I don't I get another error that states x variable is already well defined...

Answer (score 0):

Just make it more verbose (and readable) so you don't need global variables:

```
$fileCount = 0
$files     = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\temp\data" -Recurse -Include @("*.txt*","*.pdf")
$fileInfo  = foreach ($file in $files) {
    $fileCount++
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        "CreationTime" = $file.CreationTime
        "Date Added"   = Get-Date
        "User Added"   = $env:UserName
        "Filecount"    = $fileCount
    }
}
Export-Csv -InputObject $fileInfo -Path $output_location -Append
```

Comment: Thank you mhu.
The above script rather than populating a csv file, I have the following output: Count Length LongLength Rank SyncRoot IsReadOnly IsFixedSize IsSynchronized
367 367 367 1 System.Object[] FALSE TRUE FALSE Also can I not format replies?

Comment: mhu, I wasn't able to get the script outputing as you wrote it, but piping $fileinfo to export-csv worked. However, that new formating doesn't seem to let me use full expressions on the right side IE "hashvalue" = {(Get-FileHash $_ -Algorithm MD5).Hash}} which is needed. My working CSV file has 200k entries and I need the formatting to remain the same.

Comment: Don't add brackets and use $file:  "hashvalue" = (Get-FileHash $file.FullName -Algorithm MD5).Hash

Comment: mhu, testing now. Removed $file: header. Oddly however, using this method, our test environment doesn't allow an MD5 hash where my code above does work.I'm not sure why. Thank you for suggesting a cleaner way of writing this. Will up-vote when I test against permissions.